# PHPExcel language for worksheet/cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

I would like to generate Excel files for custom languages. For example: When exporting an Excel file for a German customer, spell checking and number formatting should be set to German (resulting in numbers to have ',' for a decimal separator), but when exporting to an English customer, decimal separators should be set to '.'

Obviously, when not defining the language at all, the customer would see the Excel file with their **system wide language settings** anyway. But when I export the file as PDF or print it out and send it to them (which is what I do), they would see cell formatting with **my** language settings.

I know about `PHPExcel_Settings::setLocale`, but - as far as I can see - in its [current version](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation.php#L2308) this just affects formulas and currency symbols.

**And:** Is this possible at all with current versions of MS Excel (I don't own a copy of Office 2016)? I know it can be [easily done in LibreOffice Calc](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Calc/Formatting/How_can_I_use_a_dot_%28.%29_as_decimal_sign_instead_of_a_comma%3F).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to change anything for thousand and decimal separators in PHPExcel. Just work with PHP's standard float type, and the existing format masks using `,` and `.`.

This is how Excel format files always store the formatting mask, any conversion is handled by the MS Excel GUI itself.... the MS Excel GUI will automatically convert these to the values used for its own locale settings... so an English MS Excel user will see their locale thousands and decimal separators, while a German MS Excel user will see their locale thousands and decimal separators.

Likewise, locale information for language is also set inside the MS Excel GUI, as long as you ensure that all text input is entered into PHPExcel cells as UTF-8 strings and not using any other charset

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! 

Okay, so you're saying, that even in current versions of MS Excel there's no easy way to print/export files and have numbers with decimals separators different from what is set as the system default?

Comment: So tell me how you're printing/exporting numbers with decimals from MS Excel? Because it seems largely unrelated to anything with PHPExcel unless you're using PHPExcel's PDF writer rather than one of the Excel Writers

Comment: That is true - if there **is no way** to do it in Excel (even manually), than truly my question was unrelated to PHPExcel - sorry! (I only assumed, that it might be possible as it is [possible in LibreOffice](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Calc/Formatting/How_can_I_use_a_dot_%28.%29_as_decimal_sign_instead_of_a_comma%3F). And if it were possible there might have been a PHPExcel method for it...)

Comment: Oh wow - I just saw that you're from the core team - what an honour! Thanks a lot for putting so much work into this - I love PHPExcel!